# MySQL - 1toN, Select items from table1 that have table2.attribute=1 AND table2.attribute=2

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am using four tables, I will call them "products", "attributes_categories", "attributes" and "product_has_attributes". Every product in "products" has many attributes in "product_has_attributes", like this:

```
[product_has_attributes] : product1
attribute_id=1 (Brands->Sony)
attribute_id=4 (Screen size -> 20")
attribute_id=7 (Colors -> Black)
attribute_id=8 (Colors -> White)
```

products and product_has_attributes are left joined on products.id = product_has_attributes.product_id

A simple SELECT correctly returns each product as many times as its attributes.

Now, I want to select all products that have:

```
product_has_attributes.attribute_id=1 AND 
product_has_attributes.attribute_id=4 AND 
(product_has_attributes.attribute_id=7 OR 
product_has_attributes.attribute_id=8)
```

But, as it's expected, product_has_attributes.attribute_id can't be 1 AND 4 AND (7 OR 8) at the same time... So no records are returned.

How can I build the SQL so it returns the records in the logic I described?

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.  It's not massively efficient.

```
 select * from products 
 where product_id in (
     select product_id from product_has_attributes where attribute_id = 1
 )
 and product_id in (
     select product_id from product_has_attributes where attribute_id = 4
 )
 and product_id in (
     select product_id from product_has_attributes where attribute_id in (7, 8)
 )
```

Comment: Thank you, but it returns only the first matching row for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out (using your input). Thanks Chrisky!